# How to delete references in MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, monodevelop

Running MonoDevelop-Unity, version 5.9.6, Mac

Using Project->Edit References->.Net Assembly tab I have clicked Browse and added reference to a .dll library generated in another MonoDevelop Project.  Now I would like to delete that line as it appears in the .Net Assembly tab.  Cannot figure out how to do it.
Delete key, context menu(none appears), no button or widget to remove.
Searched online everywhere.  Nothing in the docs that I could find.  Opened project and other associated files as text, nothing there.  Deleted and recreated the project containing the .dll, and the reference just shows up again.

So I would like to delete lines for Factory.dll, Serialize.dll and Task.dll, all of which are output binaries from other Projects entered via the Browse button on the dialog.

How is this list of references edit for deletion?

[image]

Comment: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/01/05/discontinuing-support-for-monodevelop-unity-starting-in-unity-2018-1/ You might switch to other IDE products. For MonoDevelop, you should be able to edit the project file directly to remove anything you don't like (unless it comes from MSBuild targets file.

Comment: Did you try selecting the Reference in the Solution window, right clicking and selecting Delete?